# How are R-square and mean absolute error related? Which is more important for evaluating performance?

Tags: regression, econometrics, r-squared, mse

I have some data which is divided into training and test.
I ran regression using training data and got an R-square value of 0.8, and a mean square error of 10 using the original and predicted values on test data.

After that, I changed the independent variable in the regression and got an R-square value of 0.85, and a mean square error of 12 using the original and predicted values on test data.

My questions are that:

How is it possible that R square improved while error increased?
If R-square is calculated only on training data, is it even relevant?
while comparing the models? Given the above example, which model should I select as better, the one with a higher R square or the one with lower error?

Note: Adj R square also follows the same trend. So it does not matter whether R square or adj.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are referring to. In the title you mention the mean absolute error but in the question you speak about the mean squared error. Is this about: **(1)** a discrepancy between mean squared error and mean absolute error (a discrepancy that can happen with the same errors for the same data set)  **(2)** or a discrepancy between $R^2$ and mean squared error on the training data vs. validation/test data (discrepancy that can happen because of different errors in different data sets)?

Answer (score 1):

In-sample fit (which you are assessing using $R^2$) is a notoriously poor guide to out-of-sample prediction accuracy (which you are assessing using the MSE). If you add enough random predictors to your model, your $R^2$ will eventually reach $1$ - but of course those random predictors will not be helpful in predicting. (Adjusted $R^2$ is slightly better.) This is *overfitting*. If you are interested in your model's predictive performance, I would always go with the MSE on a holdout set, or from a cross-validation.